# PHP Laravel - Redis connection using URL wirh user and pass

Tags: php, laravel, redis, predis, phpredis

I'm trying to do a PHP Redis connection. I explored the phpredis and the predis packages and didn't find a way to include the username and password URL connection string.

This is because I receive a environment variable of the redis connection string in this format:
tls://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}

I can change the order/format of the url string on the environment variable.
How do I know the final format of the connection string used on phpredis ou predis?
How can I indicate the username / password on the redis URL string, for the predis or phpredis?

I'm not restricted to predis or phpredis. I can use another if you have any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Redis has the parameter `requirepass` for password and no parameter for user. Meaning I do not think a particular user is needed nor specified, unless you can verify otherwise.

You can convert the url to array params like so

```php
[
  'host'     => parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST),
  'password' => parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PASS),
  'port'     => parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PORT),
  'database' => parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH),
]
```

To support your config in both local development and production you need something like this in you `config/database.php`

```php
...
'default' => ($url = env('REDIS_URL'))
    ? [ // production config
        'host' => parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST),
        'password' => parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PASS),
        'port' => parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PORT),
        'database' => parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH),
    ]
    : [ // original local config
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
    ],
...
```

Note, I assume your env variable is named `REDIS_URL`, please change that accordingly.